# How to get JSON file from google drive?

Tags: json, google-drive-api

I have a JSON file uploaded on google drive, I am trying to parse it in my android app. How can I get the link where it's only JSON file.

I have tried to download the file from public link and using the downloading link as the url to JSON, but looks like that link expires after a few hours.

Also, I have tried "https://googledrive.com/host/FILE_ID" but this is also not working.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you said downloading link, what API method did you use?

Comment: @noogui I opened the public link, and downloaded the file from the button from upper right hand corner, then just copied the path from which file was being downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

Try this endpoint, it might work for you.
It will download your file

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=YOUR_ID
```